# .net Math.Round weird behavior after printing

Tags: c#, .net

This question is neither a joke nor spam. We have noticed a weird behavior of Math.Round after printing on an HP OfficeJet Pro 8600. This is observed in .net 2.0 and .net 4.0.

The problem is reproducible with this code.

```
double test = 1265.26777777;
MessageBox.Show("decimal : "+Math.Round(Convert.ToDecimal(test),2).ToString()+
         " -- "+"double : "+Math.Round(test,2).ToString());
```

The result shown is 1265.27 -- 1265.27 -> OK

We print some copies to the HP printer (2 or 3 print jobs)

The result is now 1265.27 -- 1265.26

This difference of 1 cent may be reproduced with any value of test.

Does somebody have a start of rational explanation to this behavior?

Thanks in advance for help.

Best regards,

Guy

Comment: Difference of one *cent* -if you're talking about money, `double` is *definitely* the wrong data type to be using.

Comment: How are you printing?  Obviously you're not printing that string directly - some methods will truncate rather than round.  And a printer does no rounding or truncating - it just prints whatever text you give it.

Comment: It may be a buggy driver that changes the floating point control state in an unanticipated manner and doesn't restore it.

Comment: How are you printing? Using FastReport.

Comment: Is the print job related to this application at all, or can it be anything from the whole system?

Comment: After printing, throw an exception intentionally, and catch it.  That will reset the floating point processor.  If that makes a difference then you'll want to throw that printer away, perhaps.

Comment: Is the print job related to this application at all : yes, our application launch the print job

Comment: After printing, throw an exception intentionally, and catch it... Done, but same behavior

Answer (score 4):

Here is the solution:

```
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]        
public static extern int _fpreset();
```

and calling _fpreset() after printing solves this problem.

> Hans Passant: That will reset the floating point processor.

This was the right way! See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kfy34skx.aspx) for information about _fpreset.

Thanks to everybody for the successful brainstorming.

Comment: The original Microsoft VBScript and JScript engines reset the floating point chip state after every call to an external component for precisely this reason; there are many buggy components out there in the world that modify the global state of the chip. In the particular case I was concerned about, some components would turn overflows into exceptions rather than silent overflows, which would then crash the process. You might consider reporting the bug to your driver vendor.